# Magento 2 how to add custom attribute to register form?

Tags: magento2, eav-attributes, create-account

I have created an attribute ZipCode just for the registration of a new customer.

In **eav_attribute** table it exists and it's created correctly. However I have not managed to put the attribute in the new account form fields.

Here is my code:

InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace Kage\RegisterForm\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface 
{
    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Config
     */
    private $eavConfig;

    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Installs data for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $setup->startSetup();

        $attributeCode = 'register_zip_code';
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, 'register_zip_code', [
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Zip Code',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
            'visible' => true,
            'source' => '',
            'backend' => '',
            'user_defined' => true,
            'is_user_defined' => false,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'is_used_in_grid' => false,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
            'position' => 1000,
            'default' => 0,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
            CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
            CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
            null,
            $attributeCode);

        $registerZipCode= $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode);
        $registerZipCode->setData('used_in_forms', [
            'adminhtml_customer',
            'customer_account_create',
            'customer_account_edit'
        ]);
        $registerZipCode->getResource()->save($registerZipCode);

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

customer_create_account.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_form_login">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Kage_RegisterForm::form\register.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

register.phtml

```
<fieldset class="fieldset create account" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Additional Information') ?></span></legend>
    <p>
    <div class="field required regulation">
        <label for="regulation" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo __('Zip Code') ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" name="register_zip_code" id="register_zip_code" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Zip Code') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}">
        </div>
    </div>
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

The closes thing I achieved, was that the create new account form was blank, I don't want to replace fields there, I just wan't to add this extra field there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your install data script successfully installed your custom attribute, now you just need to override addition information **`.phtml`** file and set your custom attribute in that.

Create **`Vendor/TestModule/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="additional_zipcode" template="Kage_RegisterForm::form\register.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Create **`Vendor/TestModule/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml`**

```
<fieldset class="fieldset create account" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Additional Information') ?></span></legend>
    <p>
    <div class="field regulation">
        <label for="regulation" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo __('Additional Zipcode') ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" name="additional_zipcode" id="additional_zipcode" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Additional Zipcode') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:false}">
        </div>
    </div>
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Hi, thanks, but it's still not showing the extra field, I'm searching for the field when click create new account but see no extra field

Comment: After change you run setup:upgrade command

Comment: Thanks it works. I found that register.phtml inside form folder did not work, so I put it out from that folder and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

The layout file will be **customer_account_create.xml** not **customer_create_account.xml**

And please change the content as below

**From:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_form_login">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Kage_RegisterForm::form\register.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

**To:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="register_zip_code" template="Kage_RegisterForm::form\register.phtml""/>
        </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: I have modified it, but still cannot see the new field :(